# Extract Protected Request Response from AWS SDK for PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm working with the new Amazon ElasticTranscoder service, and am new to working with the AWS-SDK. I have a successful script created that runs a `createJob` request, transcoding an Amazon S3 file from one format to another.

The problem is, I can't seem to access the response `$data` that is returned when the request is made. I can see it, and it contains the information I need, but I receive this error when I attempted to store it:

> Fatal error:  Cannot access protected property Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model::$data

Here's what my request looks like:

```
<?php
// Include the SDK
require 'aws.phar';
use Aws\ElasticTranscoder\ElasticTranscoderClient;

// Setup the trancoding service tool(s)
$client = ElasticTranscoderClient::factory( array(
    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'region' => 'us-east-1'
) );

// Create a new transcoding job
$file_name = '1362761118382-lqg0CvC1Z1.mov';
$file_name_explode = explode( '.', $file_name );

$webm_transcode_request = $client->createJob( array(
    'PipelineId' => '1362759955061-7ad779',
    'Input' => array(
        'Key' => $file_name,
        'FrameRate' => 'auto',
        'Resolution' => 'auto',
        'AspectRatio' => 'auto',
        'Interlaced' => 'auto',
        'Container' => 'auto',
    ),
    'Output' => array(
        'Key' => $file_name_explode[0] . '.webm',
        'ThumbnailPattern' => $file_name_explode[0] . '-thumb-{resolution}-{count}',
        'Rotate' => '0',
        'PresetId' => '1363008701532-b7d529' // BenchFly MP4
    )
) );

// Print the response data
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $webm_transcode_request->data );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to find some documentation on handling response requests with PHP and the AWS SDK, any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use the [`toArray()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Guzzle.Common.Collection.html#_toArray) method, listed under "Methods inherited from `Guzzle\Common\Collection`" in [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Guzzle.Service.Resource.Model.html).

   e.g.

   ```
   $webm_transcode_request->toArray();
   ```
2. Just directly access indexes of the `$data` property as if they were indexes of the response object. This works because the `Guzzle\Service\Resource\Model` class implements PHP's magic [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface to make array-like access operate on the `$data` property.

   e.g.

   ```
   $response = $ec2Client->describeInstances();

   // Gets the value of the 'Reservations' key of the protected `$data` property
   // of `$response`
   var_dump($response['Reservations']);
   ```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much iPhoney! I knew that there had to be a method that could handle it somewhere.

Comment: @iPhoney and Kevin I am trying to do same thing but no luck. I am doing $responseArray = Collection::toArray($response); but $resonseArray remains null. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: @KevinLeary I am doing $responseArray = Collection::toArray($response); but $resonseArray remains null. Please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: 7 years later, but I think it should be `$responseArray = $response->toArray()` if you're going that route.